# Overlap (or convert) a raster in shapefile with R software

Tags: r, tiff, r-raster, converters

I have an .TIFF file (raster) for Latin America and .shp file (shapefile) for brazilian municipalities and I want to overlap both but I want sum all the informations that a raster have.

In my case,  I have a TIFF file is about light pollution. Every point in raster represent one light information that ranging from 0-63. The shapefile have only the geometry.

In the end I want that every information in municipality return the sum (or mean) of all the raster points.

Someone knows that's possible in R software?

Many thanks

I Cannot give an example because TIFF file is too big but I sending an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5TkB.png)

I want to overlay a map like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bONbR.png), but with smaller dimensions

Comment: Allow me to suggest you to kindly provide examples of what you have tried so far. A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
require(raster)

rs=raster("pathToTiff.tif")
shp=shapefile("pathToShapefile.shp")

##to get the sum of all raster values within in each administrative area:
##assuming that they are in the same CRS, if not in same CRS run this first - shp=spTransform(shp,crs(rs))
extract(rs,shp,fun=sum)
```